# How to use fprintf with a dynamically allocated unsigned char* array in C

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to write a unsigned char* array to a file.

A minimal working example of the code that I've tried so far is (assume fp is correctly initialised):

```
unsigned char* x; int i; int j; int sizeOfx;
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    x = // getter function with parameter i
    sizeOfx = // getter function that returns the number of elements in x
    for (j=0; j<sizeOfx; j++) {
        fprintf(fp,"%s",x[j]);
    }
}
```

i.e. I'm going through the char array one element at a time and writing it to the file.

However, I get the error

```
format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char*’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If the `unsigned char *` is null-terminated then you don't need to print each char individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%s` is used to print a string, so you would need to change `x[j]` to `x` to 'fix' your error.

As you really seem to want to write each `char` separately, you need to think how you want to store the 'elements' (characters of the string).

You can use `%c` to store their value as an ASCII value in the file (which is basically identical when using `%s` and `x`, unless you want to write more/less than the complete string).

Or you can store the 'element values' as integers, ie textual values using the characters 0-9, using `%d`. Or maybe hexadecimal using `%x` using the characters 0-9 and a-f.

So it is up to you how you want to store the 'elements' of `x`.

Answer (score 2):

Try %c (for character printing) instead of %s.

Alternatively you could write the print line as follows:

```
fprintf(fp,"%s",(char*)x[j]);
```

which statically casts that pointer at x[j] back to a string (essentially), then if the string coming into that loop were "abcdef", then the output would be as follows:

```
"abcdefbcdefcdefdefeff"
```

This is where c is completely open to do what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks very much! I was having trouble writing the whole array to the file in one go, so I wanted to write it element by element. It appears to work?

Comment: `x[j]` is not a pointer, so casting it using `(char *)` results in problems... You need an additional `&`: `(char *) &x[j]` or just use `x + j`...